# To prove the collection is locally finite

Tags: general-topology

If $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$ such that $d(x_m,x_n)>\epsilon$ for all $m\neq n$ and for some $\epsilon>0$, then how to prove or disprove that the collection $\{B(x_n,\epsilon/4):n\in \mathbb N\}$ is locally finite? Here $B(x_n,\epsilon/4)=\{y\in X:d(x_n,y)<\epsilon/4\}$.

A collection $\mathcal C$ of subsets of $X$ is said to be locally finite if for each $x\in X$ there is a neighbourhood $N_x$ of $x$ such that $N_x$ intersects only finitely many members of $\mathcal C$.

I am stuck in the case when $x\in X$ satisfies $d(x_n,x)>\epsilon/4$ for all $n$; I am unable to find a positive lower bound of the set $\{r>0:B(x,r)\cap B(x_n,\epsilon/4)=\emptyset ~\forall n\in \mathbb N\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in X$ and take $0<\delta <\frac {\epsilon} 4$. Claim: $B(x,\delta)$ intersects at most one of the sets $B(x_n,\epsilon /4)$: Suppose there exists $y \in B(x,\delta) \cap B(x_n,\epsilon /4)$ and $z \in B(x,\delta) \cap B(x_m,\epsilon /4)$ with $n \neq m$. Then $d(x_n,x_m)\leq d(x_n,y)+d(y,x)+d(x,z)+d(z,x_m)<\epsilon /4+\delta+\delta+\epsilon /4=\epsilon /2+2\delta <\epsilon$. This contradicts the hypothesis.

Comment: i.e. the collection is even locally discrete.